# Xamarin.Mac Could not link assemblies. Reason: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: macos, xamarin.mac

I have a Xamarin.Mac application that I can't get to build after upgrading Xamarin.Mac.  The project builds on Xamarin.Mac 2.8.2.22, but after upgrading to 3.0.0.393 (also tried 2.10.0.99) I get this error during the '_CompileToNative' step of the build:

Error MM2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (MM2001) (MyApp)

In the build output I can see the LinkMode is set to None and I've also tried using the -nolink argument, but still getting this link assemblies error.  My understand is that there shouldn't be any linking on Xamarin.Mac, so why is it even attempting the linking?

The project uses .NET Framework v4.5 with the Unified API and Xcode is at 8.2.1.

Comment: I believe it has been reported by other users as a Mono.Cecil issue. You would have to wait till Xamarin resolves that and ship a new update. Xamarin.Mac now also supports AOT, so linking is normal.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't necessarily crashing inside any linking step, mmp is the packager tool which creates your native launcher application and your bundle.

MMP should *never* crash like that, full stop. That is a bug that needs to be fixed.

Please go into your project configuration and add

> -v -v -v -v -v

to your additional mmp arguments, do another build, and file a bug (preferably with a project reproducing the error) [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/index.cgi).